# In odoo how to access rights for employee and manager are working for employee form?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

In Odoo, if I log in with an employee it shows employee form as a read-only and if I log in with the admin then I am able to edit all data. How is it managed?

I wanted to do same functionality for a custom user which I have added. If I log in with that user then some of the fields of employee form should be editable and some of them should be read-only.

I tried with security file but it is hiding my fields which I need to show as read-only.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure your user group access rights on Administror Menu > Users > Groups and set Access Rights as you want